# update_recordset and array field

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

When I'm trying to update a table with an array field using `update_recordset` statement I'm getting the following compilation error:

> Operand types are not compatible with the operator.

Here is my code:

```
update_recordset Table1 setting
    ArrayField = Table2.ArrayField 
join Table2
    where Table2.IdField == Table1.IdField;
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array fields do not work well with `update_recordset`.

You may have success with addressing the individual fields `arrayField[1]` etc. but I remember failing even that.

You may have to revert to `while select forupdate`.

Comment: Thanks Jan, I've tried with addressing the individual fields `arrayField[1]` but it also doesn't  work.